# Simple login without encryption in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a very simple login script (beginner at PHP) and here is my code. I can't figure out how to redirect after true login credentials. I know this probably is a duplicate but I can't figure this out without help on my exact script (as mentioned above I'm not that good).

**update:** So I have fixed name in password, form method, and the redirect . But now I'm getting to a empty page, something is wrong with my function as one comment earlier. I'm also a dummie at MySQL can someone help me further? My code is updated

**Another update**
Okay so i have finished all of my script, but the problem is my sql functions. So does anyone know mysqli and can translate it?

```
    <?php $tilkobling = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","login_form");



    if(isset($_POST["name"], $_POST["password"]))
        {

            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];

            $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT username, password
                                    FROM user
                                    WHERE username = '".$name."'
                                    AND  password = '".$password."'");

            if(mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0 )
            {
                $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;
                $_SESSION["naam"] = $name;
                header("Location: information_site.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'The username or password are incorrect!';
            }

    }
     ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <h2>bypass to <a href="information_site.php">information site</a></h2>
        <div class="login-page">
          <div class="form">
            <h1>Login</h1>

            <form method="post" class="login-form">
              <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="username"/>
              <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
              <button name="submit">login</button>
              <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="create_an_account.php">Create an account</a></p>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
              $('.message a').click(function(){
           $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where is session_start? Your mixing mysqli_* and mysql_* functions, also header needs to go in the if condition block not before the check. the form is doing a GET and not POST, password input field is missing a name, where is jquery lib? button is not type="submit"... I wont mention the SQL injection. ok

Comment: redirect with header or echo java script redirect with window.location

Comment: so you kind of fixed this from your other post https://stackoverflow.com/q/49244204/ and yet, what you posted still will **not** work. Look at the apis you're using here and tell me if they go well together.

Comment: This query has a SQL injection vulnerability in it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using mysqli connector and mysql functions so let's assume you'll use mysql for all

> $tilkobling = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
>
> mysql_select_db( "login_form", $tilkobling );

and you'll need to add session_start() before using/setting any session variables

> **session_start();**
>
> $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;

Comment: site does not work at all if a put:                                                                                                                                                           
    **$tilkobling = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");

    mysql_select_db( "login_form", $tilkobling );** at top under session start?

Answer (score -1):

Your header needs to be in the true portion of the if/else, which is where you set your `$_SESSION` variables, here you are:

```
        if(mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0 )
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;
            $_SESSION["naam"] = $name;
            header("Location: information_site.php");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you Tried the HTML meta tag, this subtitutes the header() function.
Of course initially convert it into PHP code. Like this:

```
Echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=put your url in here to the page you like to redirect to'>" ;
```

This should probably operate correctly.